# Hashtable not returning value via used function

Tags: function, powershell, output, hashtable

I've got a problem with my Powershell code.
I'm currently trying to use a hash table to assign a certain output to a given input value, but the function does not display the desired output.

```
$ComponentHashTable = @{
1 = 'Test1';
10 = 'Test10';
100 = 'Test100'}

function Output-Status ($Entry)
{
    Write-Host ($Entry + $ComponentHashTable.($Entry.Substring(($Entry.LastIndexOf(".")) + 1)))
}

$Entry = '10.10.10.10'

Output-Status ($Entry)
Read-Host
```

From my understanding it should be giving the following output:
`10.10.10.10 Test10`

Instead it is only returning the following:
`10.10.10.10`

The code given above is simplified, but is basically identical to the code I'm trying to get working.

I would appreciate any help with this, as I've been trying to get this working for some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@iRon's answer is absolutely correct. I have a different version where you still use integers as keys in the hash table, but calculate the index as an int:

```bsh
function Output-Status ($Entry)
{
    $key = [int]$Entry.Substring(($Entry.LastIndexOf(".")) + 1)
    Write-Host $Entry $ComponentHashTable[$key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7) keys are of type `[object]`.
Meaning an integer `1` is a different key then a string `'1'` (and you can have both -different object- keys in one hash table):

```
$Hashtable = @{}
$Hashtable.Add(1, 'Int')
$Hashtable.Add('1', 'String')
$Hashtable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              String
1                              Int
```

In your case, you need to use string keys to be able to compare them with other string keys:

```
$ComponentHashTable = @{
'1' = 'Test1';
'10' = 'Test10';
'100' = 'Test100'}
```